# How to make complete masonry box clickable - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a site: http://weltreise.inomex.ch/

I have three columsn Monsonry. I'm trying to make the complete each box clickable to complete post. Currently, only read more takes me to complete article. Any idea how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: wrap anchor tags around the article box.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running the loop that delivers content to the blocks (plugin, custom template, etc.)

You need to make sure the link tags are being placed around the entire block, not just the "read more" link.

Comment: I absolutely have no idea :/

Comment: Are you using a plugin to create the masonry blocks? Or is this a premium template that creates the blocks?

Comment: This is a premium theme called Suave

Comment: You are probably going to have to contact the theme author, who will know how to do this. Essentially, you need the `<a>` tags to be on the article class instead of the button class.

Comment: That I know but I cannot find the freaking layout in any php file :/ any idea where will it be or in which form ?

Comment: I agree that its a bad idea to go in and change any php - any updates will likely wipe out your changes. I think there's probably a way within the theme to make this change without having anyone do any custom coding, its just impossible to know without seeing the code. Ask the author.

Answer (score 0):

Author won't change theme just for you. It is also bad practice to change php file code by yourself, because of all updates and stuff. I would suggest that you add custom javascript(jQuery) (it is dirty solution, but it should work). Also be careful. Even if you wrap masonry brick with anchor(a), you should remove links that are inside that brick -> you should change anchor(a) with something else (span).